# Undefined name WebView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I'm now having some trouble regarding `Undefined name  WebView`. I'm using `minSdkVersion 20` in `build.gradle`. This is what I have and this error only happened when I upgraded my flutter version to 3.7.11 today.

*pubspec.yaml*

```
webview_flutter: ^4.1.0
```

*webviewpage.dart*

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

.....
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView(); // Webview undefined error
}

....
child: WebView( // The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the type '_WebViewPageState'
           zoomEnabled: false,
```

How can I possibly resolve this error?

Comment: Have you restarted your code editor?

Answer (score 5):

This is because the `webview_flutter: ^4.1.0` does not use `WebView` class anymore.

First possible solution is downgrading your `webview_flutter` to version 3.0.4

Second solution: you have to update your code as it described [here](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/versions/4.2.0) for the actual version of `webview_flutter`.